# VS Code: NPM scripts keeps loading when run is pressed

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, npm-scripts

At the side panel on NPM Scripts. If I press run; the script keeps loading and does nothing.

See the images below:

[image]

If I run the script in the terminal manually it works.

I don't know how to fix this, maybe a setting or something that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed in my settings.json

```
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Cmder": {
      "path": "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe",
      "args": [
        "/k",
        "C:\\Program Files\\installed-files\\cmder\\vendor\\git-for-windows\\bin\\bash.exe"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder",
```

I used another terminal instead of the default. This was the cause of it.